# CHECK(call) function get error in Google Colab

Tags: c++, cuda, google-colaboratory, nvidia

I just copied a function from normal `CHECK(call)` function in CUDA and run with `nvcc_plugin` in Google Colab

```
#define CHECK(call)
{
    const cudaError_t error = call;
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        printf("code:%d, reason: %s\n", error, cudaGetErrorString(error));
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

But it raises an error

```
/tmp/tmpvc2kvnuh/9c0f913f-6a2c-420d-9e3a-94c6e3123f7f.cu(9): error: expected a declaration
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define CHECK(call) \
{\
    const cudaError_t error = call;\
    if (error != cudaSuccess)\
    {\
        printf("Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);\
        printf("code:%d, reason: %s\n", error, cudaGetErrorString(error));\
        exit(1);\
    }\
}
```

You have to add backslashes, if you want to have a multi-line macro.